# Adobe Flex .swf Cache

Tags: apache-flex, caching, flex3, flash

I have found to reload the .swf file everytime so the user has the latest version, add the following code to eliminate caching by the browser:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Anyone have other suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Add a cachebuster. This is a string `?<random text>` after the swf url.

Answer (score 3):

The meta tag only instruct the browser not to cache the html page, but not its assets.  To avoid caching, instead of embedding the SWF like `"foo.swf"`, try it like `"foo.swf?c=" + new Date().getTime()`

The same trick goes for any other embedding dynamic assets including videos, audios as well as dynamic images.